# JQuery scroll function directs to wrong section of website

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling, sections

So I have figured out how to get my smooth scrolling working on my portfolio website, but it seems the links direct to wrong sections.

My anchor tags direct (href) to the right section, however after using them once or twice it seems to bug out.

**Relevant code:**

### Index.html

```
    <section id="nav" class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <a class="js-scroll-trigger btn btn-lg btn-nav" href="#about">About me</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <a class="js-scroll-trigger btn btn-lg btn-nav" href="#work">My work</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <a class="js-scroll-trigger btn btn-lg btn-nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</section>

<!-- Import js -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
```

### Scrolling-nav.js

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
```

My page (live preview) can be found here:
[Live Preview](https://mrdylan123.github.io/portfolio/)

Github repo:
[Repository](https://github.com/mrdylan123/portfolio/)

An example scenario where it occurs would be:

- click on the arrow button to scroll to navbar
- click an item on the navbar

What could be a possible cause of this?

**

> EDIT: It was caused by my css property on HTML, Body: Overflow-x
>
> After removing that it worked. Thanks to @Alon Eitan

**

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question 6 hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695839/js-scrolling-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-my-website

Comment: No, thats when the scrolling didn't work at all. I have fixed that problem now, but now this occurs.

Comment: Oh, cool. Can you please create a [mcve] that demonstrate the problem? Each question is required to include the **relevant** code in the question itself, so it will be helpful for future users with similar problem in future, while links might change/removed over time and make the question obsolete

Comment: Added relevant code.

Comment: Can you try and remove `overflow-x: hidden;` from `html, body, .container, .container-fluid` (line 8 on style.css)

Comment: Huh. Removing that fixed it. It seems that somewhere in my #aboutme section horizontal overflow occurs. I cant find out why though. I'll update my github aswell so you can see it live.

Comment: The issue is that `.nopadding` class, adding `margin: 0 -15px !important;` instead of `margin: 0 !important;` should solve it

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I've been stuck there for a while. I have removed the .nopadding classes altogether from my code. The only problem I face now is the text in .aboutme is too long for the image too fit to the left of it.

Comment: Not sure I understand, it looks perfectly fine to me

Comment: Does the blue #aboutmediv not exceed the image in height, causing it to leave a blue row underneath on some screens?

Comment: Changing `padding: 2% 10% 2% 10%;` to `padding: 2% 10% 0 10%;`  for the `.aboutme` class should solve it